# How to write production-ready single consumer?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

The following is a trivial implementation for a single consumer of a blocking queue. My question is, what additional code should I have to make it production-ready? Assume that I need this consumer to stay around forever.

A few questions, for example:

1. Is while(true) good enough?
2. What to do when I get an InterruptedException so that I can try to resume what I was doing?
3. What happens if the thread hangs?
4. What happens if the thread terminates due to an exception?

I guess my overall question would be some ideas around implementing management and monitoring of this single-thread consumer. Or whether there are existing libraries that provide a base implementation.

Thanks a lot!

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue queue;

    public Consumer (BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                Object task = queue.take();
                ...
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService which will solve most of your issues and is production ready (has been for many years)

Answer (score 4):

> Is while(true) good enough?

Oops.  @Cratylus makes a good point that you should always use:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

You need to be religious with the catching of exceptions -- possibly even catching `RuntimeException` and maybe even `Throwable`.  At least you should consider catching and logging a message before quitting.

> What to do when I get an InterruptedException so that I can try to resume what I was doing?

It depends on what you want the thread to do.  IMO, when a thread is interrupted it should be (uh) interrupted.  Since `thread.stop()` is deprecated for lots of reasons, `thread.interrupt()` really is the only way to stop a thread from running.  This means that it should clean up and exit.

```
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // always a good practice to re-interrupt
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // but now what to do?  I vote for stopping the thread
    return;
}
```

> What happens if the thread hangs?

This should never happen unless you have bugs in your program.  It may wait forever on `queue.take()` but an interrupt should kick it out.

Be careful of multiple `synchronized` sections to protect against deadlock.  Be sure to use the `java.util.concurrent.*` classes (`BlockingQueue`, `Executors`, ...) to lesson the chance of user code causing problems.  Use the `Atomic*` classes.  All data shared between threads need to be properly `synchronized` or `volatile`.

> What happens if the thread terminates due to an exception?

What do you want to happen?  You should (again) religiously catch exceptions if that is what you want to do.  If you want the thread to stop when it sees an exception then I'd catch the exception, log it, and then clean up and return.  There is no easy answer to exception handling.

Comment: I guess my question is more on the management of such a consumer. How to detect if this consumer is no longer available and another one needs to created. etc.

Comment: That's harder @delta2038.  You could use a thread-pool and see how many jobs are queued and then make a decision to start another consumer if the queue is too large.  You could use the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool(...)` and start with X threads so that it can scale itself up if the queue fills. Typically you bench test your application to see what is the right value for the number of consumers.

Answer (score 3):

> Is while(true) good enough?

No. You should do `while(!interrupted)`

> What to do when I get an InterruptedException so that I can try to
>   resume what I was doing?

If you get an interrupted exception you should not resume. It is a signal to stop

> What happens if the thread hangs?

It will not if you exit on interrupt. It will hang in your current form (there is no way to stop it as you currently have coded it)

> What happens if the thread terminates due to an exception?

It terminates.Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Or just:  while(!interrupted) :-)

Comment: @mamboking:Dah...Thanks!Updated answer